# Как инсталлировать rvm на СentOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos

Как можно инсталлировать rvm на СentOS используя скаченный архив с github?

Comment: да инструкция, вроде бы, достаточно лаконична: https://github.com/rvm/rvm#any-other-operating-system , потому вопрос следует уточнить (нажав [edit]) — что именно у вас не получилось при следовании этой инструкции.